# Why does objects in findAll(Pageable pageable) switch places after updating a single field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is my repository for Order Entity that has enum Status.

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    Page<Order> findOrdersByStatus(Status status, Pageable pageable);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Order o SET o.status = :status WHERE o.id = :id")
    void updateStatus(@Param(value = "status") Status status, @Param(value = "id") long id);

        @Query("SELECT o.status FROM Order o WHERE o.id=:id")
    Status getStatusById (@Param(value = "id")  long id);
}
```

Each time user clicks on change status - this logic is invoked from Controller.

```
        if (action.equals(STATUS_ACTION_DECLINE)) orderService.updateStatus(Status.DECLINED, orderId);
    else {
        Status status = orderService.getOrderStatus(orderId);

        if (!status.equals(Status.DECLINED) && !status.equals(Status.COMPLETED))
            orderService.updateStatus(Status.values()[status.ordinal() + 1], orderId);
    }
```

This is what service methods looks like ( just delegating to repository )

```
public Status getOrderStatus(long id) {
    return orderRepository.getStatusById(id);
}
  @Transactional
public void updateStatus(Status status, Long orderId) {
    orderRepository.updateStatus(status, orderId);
}
```

Then - to return updated list of objects - findAll(paginated) is called

```
    public Page<Order> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection) {

    Sort sort = sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() :
            Sort.by(sortField).descending();

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort);
        System.out.println("PAGEABLE " + pageable);
        return this.orderRepository.findAll(pageable);  
}
```

Seems like an easy stuff, but here is a problem.
First time ( befure user clicks on update status button ) findAll has this `PAGEABLE` object that sorts by creationDate

```
PAGEABLE Page request [number: 0, size 5, sort: creationDate: ASC]
```

And findAll(pageable) returns this

```
 Order(id=1, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, updateDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 1)
Order(id=2, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, updateDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
Order(id=3, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.251971, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 1)
Order(id=4, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
Order(id=6, status=COOKING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:06:21.555237, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:06:21.555237, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
```

Seems like ok, no matter how many times I reload the page - I get the same result.
Now I click update status button on a few orders. Orders are updated and let's do findAll(pageable) again to get the updated list.

```
PAGEABLE Page request [number: 0, size 5, sort: creationDate: ASC]
```

Pageable object is the same, but list is not, though sorting should be done by creationDate and not change - 1 and 2 ids have switched places. Why is it so?

```
    Order(id=2, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, updateDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
Order(id=1, status=COOKING, creationDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, updateDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 1)
Order(id=3, status=COOKING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.251971, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 1)
Order(id=4, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
Order(id=6, status=COOKING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:06:21.555237, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:06:21.555237, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
```

Comment: The database can return rows having identical `creationDate` values in an arbitrary order. If you add another column such as `id` to the Sort, then the row ordering would be deterministic.

Comment: @ChinHuang thank you, could you please clarify, why did order of `Orders` stay the same no matter how many times I reload before an update,  after - changed a bit. Does any change in DB table make it 'reorganize' they way it returns values?

Comment: Correct, changing the data in the database caused the database to change its internal data structure for organizing the data.